# How to insert listElement to QML listModel from pyqt5 code?

Tags: python, qml, pyqt5

I want to dynamically create data with python code. I have this qml code:

**messages.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import "src/variables/fontawesome.js" as FontAwesome
import "src/lists"

Item {
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    AvatarListView{
        anchors.fill: parent
        objectName: "messages_list"
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement{
                avatar: "qrc:/src/examples/images/venkman.jpg"
                title:"Sergiy Giba"
                detail: "Cекс буш?"
            }
            ListElement{
                avatar: "qrc:/src/examples/images/spengler.jpg"
                title:"Vasya Nikorich"
                detail: "Cекс буш?"
            }
            ListElement{
                avatar: "qrc:/src/examples/images/stantz.jpg"
                title:"Jester Sunborn"
                detail: "Cекс буш?"
            }
        }
}
```

And my **main.py:**

```
class Vamblr(QQuickView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setSource(QUrl('messages.qml'))

        messages_list = self.rootObject().findChild(QObject, 'messages_list')
```

How can i use Pyqt5 to insert new ListElement?

Comment: You need to get the `ListModel` not the `ListView`, then you can use the `insert` oder `append`-function to insert new ListElements (you would insert JSON-Objects instead) http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html

Comment: Now i have this error: `TypeError: unable to convert argument 0 of QAbstractListModel.insert from 'dict' to 'QQmlV4Function*'`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you had the model in Python and just exposed it to QML for use there? That is how one would do that when using C++ as the main application language